# Syntax errors: python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I have this error using python 3.8 from the interpreter

```
>>> python hello.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python hello.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 >>>`
```

I have attempted several changes in the editor using python or env python or python3

what am I missing? Thx in advance

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you type that into your OS command line or into the python REPL?

Comment: Show us the code of hello.py - you are probably missing some () or use invalid syntax in it. [edit] and [mre[ please

Comment: This question is a tricky one. It has nothing to do with the code, but how to execute it. Everyone here has been bamboozled.

Comment: @zariiii9003 Definitely on python REPL. I could only reproduce the error on that REPL. It seems like the person is a complete beginner so it's understandable that the OP came to that error.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run your code while being in the "python shell" A.K.A `Python REPL`
You need to exit from the shell and try running your code again.

You can quit by typing `quit()` or by pressing `Ctrl-Z` on your terminal

Then you can type in `python hello.py` or preferably `python <directory_to_file>/hello.py` to run your code.

On side note:

- Try looking up a tutorial on YouTube, or reputable websites on learning python.
- Try using a popular editor, such as VS Code or PyCharm to enhance your coding experience.